# php code not working in default.ctp page in Cakephp2.8.5

Tags: cakephp

Thanks in advance, I am new to cakephp, i am using cakephp2.8.5 version. Actually i want to write a php code for counting number of records from the mysql database table comparing the ordered date column date values with the current date. I have written the code but my menus are in default.ctp page. In Order Check menu i have to show the count in numbers. default.ctp page lying in app/view/Layout/default.ctp so how to create a count value in php code without using controller.

My code will compare the current date with the table column date and calculates the count.How can i pass the variable $ordCounts into default.ctp page without creating controller page
Which is as below:

```
<?php                     

$a = 0; 

for($j=0; $j<count($ordCounts) ;$j++)   
{
    $orderDate = $ordCounts[$j]['carts']['order_date'];          
    $currentDate = $dateTime;        
    $diff = strtotime($currentDate) - strtotime($orderDate);         
    $hour = $diff/(60*60);                             
    if($hour>24)  
    {
        $a++;           
    }
} 

echo $a; 

?>
```

Comment: Do you mean how to set variables from controller to use in default.ctp page ?

Answer (score 2):

Create `beforeRender()` method in `AppController`

```
public function beforeRender(){
    parent::beforeRender();
    //here your code
    $this->set('a',$a);
}
```

`$a` variable will be available in templates

Answer (score 0):

you can create a function of the above code which counts the occurences in AppController like this

```
function countOccurences(){
    $a = 0; 
    for($j=0; $j<count($ordCounts) ;$j++)   
    {
        $orderDate = $ordCounts[$j]['carts']['order_date'];          
        $currentDate = $dateTime;        
        $diff = strtotime($currentDate) - strtotime($orderDate);         
        $hour = $diff/(60*60);                             
        if($hour>24)  
        {
            $a++;           
        }
    } 
    return $a;
}
```

and then call this function in your beforeFilterMethod in AppController

```
function beforeFilter(){
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $count = $this->countOccurences();
    $this->set('count',$count);
}
```

Comment: No I am getting some error in my default.ctp page.Actually I have created a sql query in the UsersController like this public function orderCount()
  {
      //For 24 hrs Order check for all orders 
     $counts = $this->User->query("select * FROM carts LEFT JOIN checks ON carts.orderid = checks.order_id AND carts.exam_name = checks.exam WHERE checks.order_id is null AND checks.exam is null AND carts.order_date < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY");  
     $this->set('count',$counts);        

  }

Comment: In deafult.ctp page I have to pass the variable count <?php$a = 0;  
            for($j=0;$j<count($count);$j++)    
            {
               $orderDate = $count[$j]['carts']['order_date'];          
               $currentDate = $dateTime;        
               $diff = strtotime($currentDate) - strtotime($orderDate);         
               $hour = $diff/(60*60);                             
               if($hour>24)  
               {
                  $a++;           

               }

            } 
             return $a;

Comment: but I am getting fatal error in the default.ctp page on line 120

Comment: My doubt is without creating Controller and Model for deafult.ctp page how can i pass "count" variable like this  $this->set('count',$counts); into the default.ctp page

Comment: If you do not want to create a model or controller you can always use AppController.php and can create your above function ( which contains the sql query ) there, since you are using query function you do not have to worry about the model also, So in my solution in countOccurences function you can call the query and can then access that in default.ctp. Although its not a good practice. I would suggest you to paste the error trace here

Comment: In the AppController.php i have written as <?php    
   function countOccurences(){     
     $counts = $this->User->query("select * FROM carts LEFT JOIN checks ON carts.orderid = checks.order_id AND carts.exam_name = checks.exam WHERE checks.order_id is null AND checks.exam is null AND carts.order_date < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY");
     
 }

Comment: I was not able to write large codes so i had splitted the code.Inside the  function countOccurences(){  public function beforeFilter() {
      parent::beforeRender();      
      $this->layout = 'default'; 
      $this->Auth->allow('login');     
      $counts = $this->countOccurences();
      $this->set('count',$counts);
 } this is also include

Comment: and in the default.ctp page I have written as <span class="label label-primary pull-right"><?php
                                 echo $count[0];
              ?></span>     but i got an error as Notice (8): Undefined variable: count 

[APP\View\Layouts\default.ctp, line 3]

Comment: Inside your beforeFilter function you should have called parent::beforeFilter(); Also I will recommend you to assign any random value to $count in beforeFilter function and print or echo it in default.ctp and check if its accessible there anyways

Comment: No i am getting Notice (8): Undefined variable: count [APP\View\Layouts\default.ctp, line 3]

Comment: its because you used `$counts` please check again your code `$counts = $this->User->query("select * FROM carts LEFT JOIN checks ON carts.orderid = checks.order_id AND carts.exam_name = checks.exam WHERE checks.order_id is null AND checks.exam is null AND carts.order_date < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY");`